# Real primary key size of addressing space in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, floating-point, precision

I want to store a text file line-by-line in an sqlite database, need to retrieve lines fast in order and be able to insert lines efficiently. So I was thinking about using a `REAL PRIMARY KEY` which according to sqlite Docs is a double-precision floating point number. The idea is to insert by mean with `(previous_line_id+next_line_id)/2` as the new primary key.

**Questions:**

1. How should I increment the key in the first place (without insertions) to maximize the available address space and how many lines can I insert approximately before I run out of precision?
2. Is there a fast way to reorder all real IDs in case I run out of space between two lines?
3. Is there a better way of doing this?

Regarding 3, I'm sure there are better specialized data structures, but I'm more interested in quick and dirty sqlite solutions if they work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for floating-point for this. The feature of floating-point you are seeking to use is that there can be many representable values between two line numbers *a* and *b*. But that feature is easily obtainable with integers, simply by initially numbering lines with large gaps between them.

For example, with the common IEEE 754 64-bit binary floating-point format, numbering lines 1, 2, 3, 4… would afford about 50 bits after the initial line numbers (52 bits for numbers between 1 and 2, 51 for consecutive integers between 2 and 4, 50 for consecutive integers between 4 and 8, and so on, because the point in floating-point floats). You can get a similar, and more easily understood, effect by numbering the lines with 64-bit integers 0x10000000000000, 0x20000000000000, 0x30000000000000, 0x40000000000000. Then you can insert new lines between old lines by interpolating from old line numbers as desired (just be sure the arithmetic does not overflow, which it could if the line numbers get too large).

The arithmetic for renumbering lines is simple, simply assign new numbers with whatever spacing you desire. The harder part will be maintaining database consistency—if the numbers are referred to anywhere else, the references must be updated. But that is true regardless of whether the line numbers are integer or floating-point.